# How to access gmail inbox using GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, sockets, imap, gmail-imap

We are trying to access gmail inbox from our application in Java. We can read inbox, message, add label, but we are in progress to achieve all the desired functionality.

Our conclusions:

-javax.mail embedded in GAE SDK doesn't work, we can't get the content of e-mail, it returns always null (as expected to not work with IMAP protocol).

- With the package mail.jar (https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), the libraries throws an error because there are two libraries with the same name. (javax)
- We investigated and we found a solution on Google Groups consisting in copy the files from javamail.jar to our WEB-INF/classes directory in to our project.
- After that, javamail library works but com.sun package is not recognized by our project (eclipse) so we can't get the content of an attachment indeed we need to use "com.sun.mail.util" package.

How can add this libraries to our project?

We use:

App Engine Java SDK 1.7.7
GWT 2.5.1
Java Sun 1.6
Eclipse 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure for recieving emails you should turn on the inbound mail services to true

```
<inbound-services>
  <service>mail</service>
</inbound-services>
```

There is more configuration details that you can read thro in the documentation.,

[Recieve email](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Receiving_Mail)

Comment: We are trying to access users' gmail inbox (through Oauth 2.0 and IMAP), not to receive emails in the application.

Thanks for your help.